# Return data that was not inserted in mysql table

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, csv

I have a `.csv` file which will insert data into a table through the following PHP code

```
while (($col = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
{       
    $quer = "INSERT INTO table1(username, password) VALUES('$col[0]','$col[1]')";   
    mysql_query($quer);
}
```

The username is the primary key so it should be unique. Now if the table already contains "abc" as a username and the `.csv` file is inserting "abc" again in the username column, the query won't be executed as it's primary!

Now how can I insert all unique usernames and display the ones which were not inserted from the `.csv` file?

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: @Anant Thanks !! Worked like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said `username` is `primary key` column in your table. And you want to display those records which are not inserted (due to duplicate username).So do like below:-

```
$failed_data = array();  // create an empty array
while (($col = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) { 
     $quer="INSERT into table1(username,password)values('$col[0]','$col[1]')"; 
     if(!mysql_query($quer)){  // check if query run
       $failed_data[] = array($col[0],$col[1];) // if not assign failed value to array
     } 
}
echo "<pre/>";print_r($failed_data);//print the array
```

Note:- Please read @Alex answer and follow instructions. Necessary

**A note on the `mysql_*` library functions:** Don't use them! They are [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) as of PHP 5.5, and [removed](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7) as of PHP 7! If you are learning from a tutorial, do consider reporting it to @halfer's [Awooga](http://awooga.jondh.me.uk/) database.

Answer (score 1):

```
$quer="INSERT IGNORE into table1(username,password)values('$col[0]','$col[1]')"; 
if(mysql_affected_rows()==0) echo $col[0];
```

Comment: Bad practice to use INSERT IGNORE

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to check the table first with a `SELECT` query, to see if the primary key already exists, then act accordingly.

Alternatively, if you wanted to make changes to any row that would otherwise cause a collision, you could use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`, explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). You could then check the `affected-rows` value using the `mysqli_affected_rows` function, according to the following:

> With `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, the `affected-rows` value per row is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row, 2 if an existing row is updated, and 0 if an existing row is set to its current values.

**A note on `INSERT IGONORE`:** I would advise against using any solution involving `INSERT IGNORE`, as, while preventing any errors from primary key collisions, this will also hide any other errors/warnings. That's a bad thing.

**A note on the `mysql_*` library functions:** Don't use them! They are [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) as of PHP 5.5, and [removed](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7) as of PHP 7! If you are learning from a tutorial, do consider reporting it to @halfer's [Awooga](http://awooga.jondh.me.uk/) database.

Comment: $failed_data = array(); while (($col = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) { $quer="INSERT into table1(username,password)values('$col[0]','$col[1]')"; if(mysql_query($quer)){ }else{$failed_data[] = array($col[0],$col[1])} }